# AutoCAD format for SCADA system

Tags: autocad, scada

I am working on project and my task is to export house plan from AutoCAD to some format that is most adaptable for SCADA. Any suggestion will help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't specify which HMI/SCADA package, you'll get a general answer. Since ALL packages are basically a GUI, a bitmap (.bmp) graphic will be fine for most, if not all.

One thing I do know for sure, Rockwell's FactoryTalk View will allow you to import a .dxf file, but I think this is the only package that will let you do this. WinCC and InTouch certainly don't have this kind of support.

For the sake of compatibility, an image file would be best.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of developers of open source [Scada-LTS](https://github.com/sdtabilit/Scada-LTS/tree/develop-sdtabilit).

We can add functionality of loading svg or 3dx background on view (HMI) in Scada-LTS.

Your dfx file can be converted into svg or x3d format.

For example you may use:

- http://kabeja.sourceforge.net to svg convertion.
- https://www.blender.org to x3d convertion.

Answer (score 0):

Schneider ClearSCADA is capable of importing dxf files into HMI screens with some limitations

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of SCADA work and to honest I have yet to come across a package that has a anything but garbage for a graphics editor.  The one exception is Wonderware's archestra ide...but for a home project you won't be using that!

I would recommend creating an image for a background (png, jpg, etc) and then laying your animated graphics and data on top of that.  My tools of choice are Sketchup for CAD tasks, Inkscape for vector graphic tasks, and Blender for 3d rendering.  Then I take the assets created in those tools and bring them into whatever SCADA package I'm working with.